# TFF: TensorSliceDataset

Tags: dataset, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

In the Federated learning context, I try to simulate a code with TFF so the type of my dataset is 'DatasetV1Adapter' (tf.data.Dataset) instead the dataset of emnist in the tutorial [ImageClassification](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification)   was of type  'TensorSliceDataset'

So that can cause a problem ?  must I change the type of my dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running with Tensorflow 1.X--`DatasetV1Adapter` is simply a wrapper for TF 2.x `Dataset` in the `tf.compat.v1.data.Dataset` API.

Try running `tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()` immediately after `import tensorflow as tf`, or simply upgrading to TensorFlow 2.